# ogr2ogr StringList to FGDB

Tags: geojson, file-geodatabase, ogr2ogr

I am trying to run ogr2ogr to convert geojson to FGDB, but running into an interesting edge case. In the below example I have a 'tags' field which is a string list.

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-48.83, -25.47]
        },
        "properties": {
            "a_property": "foo",
            "some_object": {
                "a_property": 1,
                "another_property": 2
            },
            "tags": ["tag01", "tag02", "tag03", "tag04", "tag05", "tag06", "tag07", "tag08", "tag09", "tag10", "tag11", "tag12", "tag13", "tag14", "tag15", "tag16", "tag17", "tag18", "tag19", "tag20"]
        }
    }]
}
```

Running this command:

```
ogr2ogr -f FileGDB out.gdb in.json -oo FLATTEN_NESTED_ATTRIBUTES=yes
```

Will return:

```
Warning 1: The output driver does not natively support StringList for field tags.
Warning 1: Cannot map OGR field type (StringList)
ERROR 1: Error (-1): Failed converting field type.
```

Is there any setting which will make ogr2ogr to convert this list to a string? Or something along those lines? Specifically one which does not require knowing the name of the field ahead of time, as it can change. I am hoping to not have to pre-process the json before running through ogr2ogr.

Changing the command to:

```
ogr2ogr -f FileGDB out.gdb in.json -oo FLATTEN_NESTED_ATTRIBUTES=yes -fieldTypeToString StringList
```

Is almost what I need actually, but it is truncating the text field to ~80 characters. The field that is actually created in the FGDB is Length 65536 though, so there should be no limit caused by that. Example with 20 tags:

```
(20:tag01,tag02,tag03,tag04,tag05,tag06,tag07,tag08,tag09,tag10,tag11,...)
```

Preferred result would be something with all of them in the field such as:

```
tag01,tag02,tag03,tag04,tag05,tag06,tag07,tag08,tag09,tag10,tag11,tag12,tag13,tag14,tag15,tag16,tag17,tag18,tag19,tag20
```

I don't care if there are () or a number, or spaces between them even. I just need all of them in the one field.

Comment: You should find two alternative ways from here http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html.

Comment: Doh, looked through that page several times today, and didn't find anything until after you said something. So `-fieldTypeToString` doesn't quiet work as I would expect since it will truncate long lists to `(27:tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4,tag5,tag6,...)` and `-splitlistfields` will end up with N number of fields, which is quite messy, and a huge pain to search against.

Comment: Paste one such feature as GML and the result you'd like to get and I will try to find some solution.

Comment: I validated the above geojson example now. If you save that as `in.json` and run the `ogr2ogr` command it will produce the example output in the 'tags' field.

Comment: There is probably a hardcoded limit at 80 characters for all formats which do not support StringList. As long as that is the case your business will be tricky. http://osdir.com/ml/gdal-development-gis-osgeo/2015-04/msg00253.html. I think I would try to do some regexp magic directly to GeoJSON. Conversion into GML keeps all the tags but that does not make things any easier. Perhaps you should write to gdal-dev and ask why that limit and how to expand it.